# How to load a Jquery data-table from a JSON response

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I have a Json data something like this

```
 var data = '{"aaData":[{"rrno":"RR201600001","name":"Vikram","dob":"2016-04-11","gender":"Male","job_profile":"Buisness Associate","graduation":"B.Tech\/B.E.","total_exp":1,"status":"Accepted"},
{"rrno":"RR201600002","name":"Rahul","dob":"1992-10-13","gender":"Male","job_profile":"Buisness Associate","graduation":"B.Tech\/B.E.","total_exp":3,"status":"Rejected"}]}';
```

Then I am loading this data in the DataTable like this

```
var table = $('#dataTable1').DataTable();
      table.ajax.url(url).load();
```

My **HTML** is like this

```
  <table id="dataTable1" class="table  table-bordered table-striped-col">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sourcing ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Dob</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Job Profile</th>
      <th>Basic / Graduation</th>
      <th>Total Experience</th>
      <th>Final Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

But I am getting a POPUp as an Alert saying

> DataTables warning: table id=dataTable1 - Requested unknown parameter
>   '0' for row 0

[image]

Comment: You've got a string there rather than an object. Try to remove the starting and ending `'`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dataTable1').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            'url':url,
            "dataSrc": "Responses"
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: nops it did not work I just See Processing word on the table and nothing is loading and ALso `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` error in the console

Comment: I think your json format is not correct. make sure it is in correct format.

Comment: I have posted the Json and also checked it if its Valid , And it shows correct using this link http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: check carefully, in jsonlint.com it shows the error. Error: Parse error on line 1:
var data = { "aaDat
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Comment: I am updating a screen shot in my answer it shows Valid Json for me

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can Write Like This

```
var dataSet = [
[ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
[ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
[ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ]];

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: data ,
    columns: [
        { title: "Name" },
        { title: "Position" },
        { title: "Office" },
        { title: "Extn." },
        { title: "Start date" },
        { title: "Salary" }
    ]
} );
```

} );

for More reference please see this link : https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Comment: But how about using the Ajajx to load the data automatically , I have a large table it will be paintaking to convert each into  array

Comment: you can use Ajax sourced data to load your large data from table by calling action from datatable I think this link will helpfull : https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html